# What is the proper way to bind a dependency property to a property of an ancestor's view model

Tags: wpf, mvvm, viewmodel

I have a user control placed in a TabItem. I want to bind the UserControl dependency property to a static property from the TabItem's ViewModel.

Using

```xml
<player:Player TrackToPLay="{Binding SelectedTrack.FullPath}" IsTrackPlaying="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type TabItem}},Path=DataContext.TrackIsPlaying,Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

seems not to fall into the dependency property value update.

Here you can see that the ViewModel's property is called TrackIsPlaying and the viewmodel is the DataContext for the TabItem.
What I am missing?

Comment: When your UserControl is placed in a TabItem, its DataContext should already be that of the TabItem. Do you perhaps intend to bind to a property of the Tab**Control**'s DataContext? And why is that property static?

Comment: Hi Clemens, actually I realized in the meantime that the bound property is directly accessible as the scope of the datacontext is present. I set the property to be static as it is updated from other viewmodels as well.